# Laravel: write image urls to JSON object

Tags: php, json, laravel, image

I have a Laravel 5.5 application where I store image urls in JSON objects.
Objects are stored like:

```
{"images": ["/images/57/image-12.png","/images/57/image-11.png"]}
```

Storing the images on web server works. Just need to add them to the JSON file to use them later.

How can I place them behind each other?

Comment: So, your actual question is how do you append text to a text file?

Comment: to the json file (it is text indeed)